# Combining ggplots erase original plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, erase

I tried to align different plots obtained by using geom_bar. When I run each plot one by one, it works well. I got what I want. But when I aggregate all of them into one multiple plot, I have always the same....

To be clear: this is the first plot which is good:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz0Sn.png)

Here what I got when I combine both plots. The first column should be the same the plot above...:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHl46.png)

I can't find the problem. This is my script:

```
##### colonne 6
i=6
col=compil[,i]
nom=names(compil[i])
maxi = max(col)
mini = min(col)

p5 <- ggplot(compil,aes(x=NIVEAU, y=col)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity",aes(width=0.85),
           fill=ifelse(col > 1, rgb(63,202,20, maxColorValue = 255),
                       ifelse (col< -1,rgb(204,0,0, maxColorValue = 255),
                               rgb(160,160,160, maxColorValue=255))) ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,color=rgb(160,160,160, maxColorValue=255))+
  coord_flip(ylim=c(-2.5,2.5)) +
  labs(x="", y="", title= nom) + guides(fill=F) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks  = element_blank(),axis.line= element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,-1,1,-1),"lines"), plot.title = element_text(size=10))
print(p5)

##### colonne 7
i=7
col=compil[,i]
nom=names(compil[i])
maxi = max(col)
mini = min(col)

p6 <- ggplot(compil,aes(x=NIVEAU, y=col)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity",aes(width=0.85),
           fill=ifelse(col > 1, rgb(63,202,20, maxColorValue = 255),
                       ifelse (col< -1,rgb(204,0,0, maxColorValue = 255),
                               rgb(160,160,160, maxColorValue=255))) ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,color=rgb(160,160,160, maxColorValue=255))+
  coord_flip(ylim=c(-2.5,2.5)) +
  labs(x="", y="", title= nom) + guides(fill=F) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks  = element_blank(),axis.line= element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,-1,1,-1),"lines"), plot.title = element_text(size=10))
print(p6)

vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 3)))
print(p5, vp = vplayout(1, 1:2))
print(p6, vp = vplayout(1, 3))
```

If someone could help me to find the mistake, I really appreciate!! Of course, I am doing something wrong but what?? 
Thank you in advance for your time and your help!

Comment: it could be due to `ggplot`'s lazy eval and you changing the same set of values for each plot, but it's hard to tell without some example data. maybe rename the variables for `colonne 7` such that the names are unique to those of `colonne 6`

Comment: To test @NathanDay's suggestion try printing p5 after generating p6.

Comment: I was thinking to do a loop for that's why I kept the same name...but you're right: I was too lazy as well! By renaming all variables as @Nathan Day said, it is now working as expexted ! Thank you very much!

Comment: just for clarity, I don't think you were lazy but I know `ggplot` is lazy at least with eval ;), glad it's working now and baptiste's answer shows how you can use standard eval instead of lazy eval, good to know for the future

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Try replacing `aes(x=NIVEAU, y=col)` with `aes_string(x="NIVEAU", y = nom, fill = nom)`, where `nom = names(compil)[i]`.

---

`col` appears to be a vector, but inside `aes()` you should pass unquoted variables from the data.frame. Passing values directly will result in surprises because ggplot2 doesn't really know where to look for "col" when building the plot – it's looking for such a variable in the data that was bound to the plot's environment, and it's not there, so next is to look in the global environment...

For the same reason, the `fill = ifelse()` stuff can't work as expected and should be removed. Mapping colours to values is the job of a scale in ggplot2, so just map `fill = nom`, then add a `scale_fill_manual(...)` or any other type of compatible scale.

(guessing, since there's no reproducible code)

Comment: Thank you @baptiste for your comment. I am not familiar with the use of "aes". Thanks to you, I learned something!! ...Unfortunately it is not working but I am not sure to use it well...I will prod a little bit further to write a better script.